# GoogleMap FATAL EXCEPTION when getFragmentManager

Tags: google-maps, android-fragmentactivity, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a map activity that works perfectly, but when I what to add a marker I get an error and   didn't found any way to resolve the problem.

> public class MapActiv extends FragmentActivity {

```
//private GoogleMap map;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);
    GoogleMap mGMap = ((MapFragment) 
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mGMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(46.24801, 26.76173))
    .title("Title").draggable(false));
}
```

}

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraTargetLat="46.24801"
    map:cameraTargetLng="26.76173"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="18"
    map:uiCompass="false"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="false"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

> 01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-19 
>   19:48:15.805:E/AndroidRuntime(16616): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:com.ex.myschoolapp.MapActiv.getFragmentManager 
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at com.ex.myschoolapp.MapActiv.onCreate(MapActiv.java:23) 01-19
>   19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121) 01-19
>   19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-19
>   19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701) 01-19
>   19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-19
>   19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   01-19 19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 01-19
>   19:48:15.805: E/AndroidRuntime(16616):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Remember that if you are using a version < 3.0 you have to use android support library)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener{
        private GoogleMap myMap;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            SupportMapFragment myMapFragment 
               = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
              myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
              myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
              myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
              myMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MiInfoWindowAdapter());
              myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    marker.hideInfoWindow();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

         @Override
         public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

             myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
         }

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));

        }

        public class MiInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater().from(getApplicationContext());
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, null);
                marker.setDraggable(true);
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater().from(getApplicationContext());
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, null);
                marker.setDraggable(true);
                return view;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The NoSuchMethodError error can be thrown when an application makes use of external libraries. Suppose your application is compiled and executed using a specific version of an external library. At some point, the external library is changed and some methods are removed or updated. If the classpath of your application is not updated and your code is not compiled using the latest version of the external library, then during runtime you will invoke a method that no longer exists and the NoSuchMethodError error will be thrown.

So i have updated Google Map API

from :com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0

To :  com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0